# Dotnet Core + Razor Pages + nginx reverse proxy + hiding url details

Tags: nginx, .net-core, razor-pages, nginx-reverse-proxy

We are developing a simple Dotnet Core 2.2 application using Razor pages to serve product information for our client's various brands.

this is an example of the URL structure which currently works when accessing kestrel directly.

- `/brands/1/products`
- `/brands/2/products`
- `/brands/1/products/23`
- `/brands/2/products/5`

What the client would like to do is configure a reverse proxy on each of their brand sites, to transparently allow a customer to browse the new site.

I have been using nginx reverse proxy to simulate this somewhat successfully when using direct access.

the following is a snippet from the nginx configuation

```
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name brand1.local;

        location /products {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/brands/1/products;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name brand2.local;

        location /products {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/brands/2/products;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }
```

this partially achieves the objective, and the following proxies work

- `http://brand1.local/products` >  `http://localhost:5000/brands/1/products`
- `http://brand1.local/products/23` > `http://localhost:5000/brands/1/products/23`
- `http://brand2.local/products` > `http://localhost:5000/brands/2/products`
- `http://brand2.local/products/5` > `http://localhost:5000/brands/1/products/5`

the problem comes in when using Razor Pages' anchor tag helper, for example

```
// /Pages/Products/Index.cshtml
@{
  foreach (var product in Model.Products)
  {
    <div>
       <a asp-page="/Products/Detail" 
          asp-route-brandId="@Model.Brand.Id" 
          asp-route-productId="@product.Id">
          @product.Name
       </a>
    </div>
  }
}
```

```
// /Pages/Products/Detail.cshtml
@page "/brands/{brandId}/products/{productId}"
```

What this results in is anchors with `href` values like `/brands/1/products/23`

This is, of course, correct when accessing the site on on `localhost:5000`

However, when we now view a product list though the nginx domains, we end up with the same `href` value e.g. `/brands/1/products/23` or `http://brand1.local/brands/1/products/23`

The problem here is now 2 fold:

- The brand ID that was "hidden" is now exposed
- When the user clicks `http://brand1.local/brands/1/products/23`, they get a 404, as there is no location (no should there be) of `/brands` on the nginx site

Is what I am trying to achieve possible?:

- Access directly through kestrel results in `href` values as they are
- Access via reverse proxy results in `href` values that exclude the `/brand/{brandId}` prefix

Answer (score -1):

Based on your setup, I guess you are trying to apply multi-tenants with `brand` is a tenant. If I correct, so your code above doesn't correct. You should change your code and read `BrandId` from Host-Header instead of url. There are sample code for reading value from header in API:

```
class ProductsController
{
     [HttpGet("{id}")]
     public IActionResult GetProducts([FromHeader] string BrandId, string id)
     {
        // Call DB to get product by BrandId
     }
}
```

In nginx, you should add one proxy header in each site. Ex:
`proxy_set_header BrandId 1`

Comment: This doesnt solve the problem. It just moves the BrandId from the url to the headers.

The issue is in how Razor/ASP.Net Core writes urls with the AnchorTagHelper.

I will probably solve this with javascript/jquery and update the hrefs when required

Comment: Nope, the anchortaghelper is correct,  because you want to pass two parameters in a next page with asp-route-brandId="@Model.Brand.Id"  and asp-route-productId="@product.Id", thus .NET Core will generate a correct href. So it stricts you to create a proxy to forward a request. In your case, you want to hide brands/{brand_id} and keep a postfix products/{product_id}, that means you should hide brand_id somewhere out of query parameter (in session, in cookie, in header, etc...).

Comment: You can imagine that you run this website in localhost:5000, so you want to have a url is http://localhost:5000/brands/1/products/1. But you add a proxy before a local web, make a proxy as a middle logic layer to forward brand_id, then when you enter http://brand1.local/products/1 will be http://localhost:5000/brands/1/products/1. That means you just take minor logic from your web to proxy. Thus you make your local web to detect two logics here: one is running on localhost and one is proxy forwarder, and the output of AnchorTagHelper are two hrefs, not one